# OneStepCheckout CSS; empty boxes are displayed when entering OnePageCheckout

Tags: html, css, magento, paypal, onestepcheckout

I hope this fits well in this category. I have a problem with the Magento OneStepCheckout module. Whenever a customer hits the checkout, there are three columns. One for the data of the customer, which are fine. The second column is showing the payment options, where you can select the desired payment option trough a checkbox.

When selected the payment option should show further information about the payment option itself (credit card, direct debit, whatsoever). The problem is that this information is in boxes, which are defined by CSS.

If you enter the checkout, then there are empty boxes with top arrows, see screenshot:
[image]

Does anyone of you is having an idea how to fix this or where to post this question exactly?

Comment: I did some research and found out that a click on the checkbox does change the element.style of each element to "display:none;". I do not find the jQuery element that does so, but it should do it in the moment the document has loaded. Right now it appears to happen only if there is a click() event. Will research further and edit, hopefully there are people out there with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution. I've copied the OneStepCheckout file payment_method.phtml into my own design folder $namespace/$themename/template/onestepcheckout/payment_method.phtml and added `style="display:none;"` to the html tag.

It now works as intended.

Line 88:

```
<dd id="container_payment_method_<?php echo $_code; ?>" class="payment-method">
    <?php echo $html; ?>
</dd>
```

to

```
<dd id="container_payment_method_<?php echo $_code; ?>" class="payment-method" style="display:none;">
    <?php echo $html; ?>
</dd>
```

I hope this helps someone! :) Cheers!